# Extracting Data from XML files only if two values are matching. ( Using .bat )

Tags: xml, batch-file

I'am looking for a .bat script which runs trough my XML files and extracts only certain Data of specified XML files. The data of these XML files should only be extracted, if the name "Ian" and position"executive" is matching. If the .bat found a matching XML file, it should only extract 3 specified values.

For Example:

Only extract if:

1. Value would be "Name=Ian"
2. Value would be "Postition=Executive"

if these values are matching, Data should be extracted for:

1.currentWork

2.shortID

3.holidaycounter

I hope it won't be too much work. XML Datas are all similar.

```
<Name="Ian" workstampIN="2017-04-06" worknumber="XXXX" editor="XXXX" Position="Executive" currentWork="engineer" shortID="543532" holidaycounter="50" >
```

etc.

Sorry I'am really new to .bat. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: is that really a colon at "holidaycounter"? Consider: batch isn't the best choice for XML (although it's possible, if the data is like your example)

Comment: Ah you were right. I corrected it :) Thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I review this type of "questions" (with no code written by the OP) I consider they as a permission to write whatever I want; for example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:<>" %%a in ('findstr "Name=\"Ian\" Position=\"Executive\"" *.xml') do (
   set "list=%%b"
   for /F "delims=" %%c in (^"!list: ^=^
% Do NOT remove this line %
!^") do set %%c
   if "!Name!+!Position!" equ ""Ian"+"Executive"" (
      echo File: "%%a", currentWork=!currentWork!, shortID=!shortID!, holidaycounter=!holidaycounter!
   )
)) > Outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider: `batch` is a bad choice for parsing XML files. That said: extract the data with a `for` loop, using proper tokens and delimiters:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%z in (*.xml) do call :extract %%z
goto :eof

:extract
for /f "tokens=1-8 delims=<> " %%a in (%*) do (
  set _%%a
  set _%%e
  set _%%f
  set _%%g
  set _%%h
)
REM set _
if %_Position%=="Executive" if %_Name%=="Ian" (
  echo 1. %_currentWork%
  echo 2. %_shortID%
  echo 3. %_holidaycounter%
) >> outputfile.txt
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! How do I add Outputfile.txt for the script ? ( So I can use the data which has been extracted for further use )

Comment: mhm I'am struggling with to configuration. May you be so kind and mark where I need to configure exactly the batch? Sorry for asking this.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q43314990.txt"
SET /a filtercount=0
SET /a fieldcount=0
CALL :filterset %*
IF %filtercount%==0 GOTO syntax
IF %fieldcount%==0 GOTO syntax
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:<=!"
 SET "line=!line:>=!"
 SET "line=!line::==!"
 CALL :filter !line!
)

GOTO :EOF

:syntax
ECHO syntax is [requiredname requiredvalue]* :: reportfieldname*
GOTO :EOF


:: set and count filters and fields

:filterset
IF "%~1"=="::" GOTO fieldset
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :EOF 
SET /a filtercount +=1
SET "$%filtercount%=%~1"
shift
SET "#%filtercount%=%~1"
shift
GOTO filterset

:fieldset
shift
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :EOF 
SET /a fieldcount +=1
SET "_%fieldcount%=%~1"
GOTO fieldset

:filter
FOR /L %%z IN (1,1,%fieldcount%) DO SET "@%%z="
SET /a matchesfound=0
:filterloop
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO report
FOR /L %%z IN (1,1,%filtercount%) DO IF /i "%~1>%~2"=="!$%%z!>!#%%z!" SET /a matchesfound+=1
FOR /L %%z IN (1,1,%fieldcount%) DO IF /i "%~1"=="!_%%z!" SET "@%%z=%~2"
SHIFT
shift
GOTO filterloop

:report
IF %matchesfound% neq %filtercount% GOTO :EOF 
SET "reportline="
FOR /L %%z IN (1,1,%fieldcount%) DO SET "reportline=!reportline! !@%%z!
ECHO(%reportline:~1%
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q43314990.txt` containing your data and some dummy data for my testing.

This procedure should solve your problem.

I am assuming that the batch command to invoke this is

> *thisbatch* cls&q43314990 name ian position executive :: currentWork shortid holidaycounter

That is (fieldname requiredvalue) repeated as many times as desired '::` (reportfiledname) repeated as many times as desired

and that case is not relevant.

The first action is to analyse the command line by `call`ing `:filterset`. If both filters and report fields are not both specified, display the required syntax.

Otherwise, read each file-line to `%%a` and thence to `line`. Process `line` to remove `>` and `<` and transform `:` to `=` (not required if the `:` should be `=` in your example), then call `:filter` to extract the required data and report.

The `:filterset` routine looks at the first token and records it as `$1` and the corresponding value required as `#1`, and keeps going with `$2,#2` etc. until `::` is found (each name/value pair is shifted out (one left) by a `shift` command and the `=` separating the name/value is helpfully replaced by <kbd>Space</kbd> byy the `call` mechanism)

When `::` is found, the remaining parameters are recorded as `_1`,`_2` etc - these are the field names to report.

The `:filter` routine first clears all `@?` values for the number of fields to be reported.

The first and second parameters provided to the `call` are then concatenated with a `>` (a character that was removed earlier, therefore can't exist and thus can be used to delimit the fields) and compared to the same string constructed from $1>#1..$?>#? On a match, count the number of matches.

Then see whether the filedname in `%1` matches each required output filedname in `_?` and if so, records the value for that parameter from `%2` into `@?`

Then `shift` twice to remove the name/value pair and procedd to the next.

When there are no parameters left, report only if the nuber of matches found is the same as the number of filters. In that case, simply build the report line by concatenating the values for each of the selected fields after a space. The final report is `echo`ed skipping the first character (which will be a space)

Comment: Wow, thanks for your detailed reply ! I'll try to work this through but since I'am really new to .bat it will take me some time I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

The given XML node is not valid as it cannot contains only [attributes](http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator). Here's the xml I've used for tests:

```
<root>
    <N Name="Ian" workstampIN="2017-04-06" worknumber="XXXX" editor="XXXX" Position="Executive" currentWork="engineer" shortID="543532" holidaycounter="50"/>
</root>
```

With [**`xpath.bat`**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) you can use the following expression:

```
call xpath.bat name.xml "//N[@Name='Ian'][@Position='Executive']/@shortID"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply also ! I never used xpath before. Will try it also !